# Requirement of SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, installation, sql-server-express, express-edition

The software I am installing requires SQL Server 2008. I have SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Version. I am having problem in the setup and finally I am arriving on the conclusion that my SQL Express can be the problem. However I am highly skeptical.

I have asked the vendors and they we cannot confirm if their software works with the Express version.

Have you ever run into a problem where a product will work with full version (of Database) and not a free version?

[Here is the Limitation of SQL Server 2008 R2](https://web.archive.org/web/20151201072641/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqlexpress/archive/2010/04/21/database-size-limit-increased-to-10gb-in-sql-server-2008-r2-express.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The following are the limitations of SQL Server Express:

- 4 GB max database size (10 GB for 2008 R2)
- Single CPU socket
- 1 GB of RAM
- No SQL Server Agent service

When you say you are having a "problem in setup", what is the problem?  The only thing in the above limitations I can think would error out is if you tried to restore a database that is greater than 4 GB (or 10 GB for R2), or if the setup application is trying to do something with SQL Server Agent.

Conversely, the setup application could potentially be just doing a basic check on the edition of SQL Server (through `@@version`) and then bombing out when it finds Express.  Hard telling not knowing your specific issue.

Comment: @EricHiggins Ah, I didn't see the "R2" in the question.  Thanks for the correction, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: My database is around 5GB. Everything works for me, except that my client software can not connect to the database. Both are on the same computer.

Comment: Unless the app vendor is programmatically detecting the version of SQL and punting if it's Express, there's no limitation on the SQL Server side. I'd check w the app vendor.@Shark, np :)

Comment: @Jackofall The software could potentially be using TCP/IP (even though it is on the same computer and would typically use Shared Memory).  Go into SQL Server Configuration Manager and enable TCP/IP protocol for the SQLEXPRESS instance.

Comment: I have done that but that did not fix the problem. The fact is they give you their own default username and password which is integrated into their database as well and that makes it complicated. But it does not look to me that express version has anything to do with it.

Comment: Is it possible they don't support named instances? Or require a specific instance name?

Comment: @SqlACID great point.